# Excel-How can I get the address of a cell instead of a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**How can I get the address of a cell instead of a value?**

For example cell A1 has the following formula which give value found in cell A33

OFFSET(A1,32,0)

Now in cell A2 I want a function that give the address of cell A1 formula result. In other words I want the value of cell A2 to be “A33”.

*******More info:
My overall goal is to have each cell of the first row return a value from column A (skipping 32 cells each time)****

So my next step will be the following:

1- Cell B1 will have the following formula:

```
    OFFSET(‘Formula that return “A33” by referencing A1’,32,0) – so this will return value in cell A65
```

2- Cell C1 will have the following formula

```
OFFSET(‘Formula that return “A65” by referencing B1’,32,0) – so this will return value in cell A94
```

And so on. I want something that I can drag and autofill easily across row 1

Comment: Does this single formula help? `=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,32,0))`?

Comment: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((LEFT(RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($A$1),LEN(FORMULATEXT($A$1))-FIND(",",FORMULATEXT($A$1))),FIND(",",RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($A$1),LEN(FORMULATEXT($A$1))-FIND(",",FORMULATEXT($A$1))))-1))*(COLUMN(B$1))+ROW($A$1),COLUMN($A$1),4))` in cell `B1` will allow you to change the `32` in the formula in `A1` (`=OFFSET(A1,32,0)`) to any reasonable number. Is that what you're looking for? Note that this is volatile due to `INDIRECT` (could 'slow down' the worksheet). If 32 is a 'known' value you could use the modified BruceWayne's `=INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($A1,32*COLUMN(B$1),0)))` in cell `B1`.

Comment: You could use this in cell `A1`: `=OFFSET(A1,32*COLUMN(A1),1-COLUMN(A1))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several challenges here. If you have duplicate data then which address will be returned? You must define data range. In short try below formula.

```
=ADDRESS(MAX(ROW(A10:A40)*(A10:A40=A1)),1,4)
```

As per your current explanation you can simply use `=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,32,0))` Let us know you feedback.

[image]